# What is "Stereotomy" by Alan Parsons Project about?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

So I read the lyrics, and it's extremely ambiguous. Is he talking to a love interest? Is he talking about mental torment? Who knows?

Here are the non-repeating stanzas for you convenience:

```
Diamond eyes
That burn me and turn me to stone
Crystalise
And freeze me in clear monochrome

Turn me to stone; do anything you want with me
Turn me to stone; do anything you want
Stereotomy
We can make it together
Do anything you want with me
Do anything you want

Scarlet minds
Possess me and I feel no shame
Silent knives
Dissect me and I feel no pain

Starlight beams
Project me in red blue and green
Velvet dreams
Protect me when I hit the screen

Turn me to stone
Do anything you want with me
Cover my eyes
There's nothing more they need to see
Turn me to stone
Before there's nothing left of me
Make me a rock
And not what I appear to be
Turn me to stone
```

Obviously, on the surface, it would seem as though it's just a patient undergoing some mental therapy involving stereotomy, and is being tormented by it emotionally. However, elements like "diamond eyes" and "we can make it together" seem to suggest that he might be addressing to a love interest. What do you think this song is actually about? Please let me know. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

[Stereotomy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stereotomy) is

> the art or technique of cutting solids (as into arches); especially :  the art of stonecutting

Comment: Not in this context. Stereotomy in psychology refers to symmetric designs or patterns formed by ink dispersion on each half of a paper. When patients are shown such patterns, psychiatrists make note of how positive/ negative of a connotation you make with the image. In this song, he is presumably making negative connotations as he seems to be disturbed by them.

Comment: So you say, but given the constant references to stone and rock, is that reasonable?

Comment: @RapidReaders, don't forget to accept the answer if you think it is correct.